# Understanding SharedMem

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Good evening guys!

I'm currently designing a desktop interface with various features using Firemonkey/FMX. One of these features is the ability to show information inside a "panel". This "panel" consists of a `title` and `context` (both `tlabel`), and an `image` (`timage`). One panel is created for each "application" that wishes to interact with my application. Each panel is named when it's created using a variable assigned when calling the procedure to create it, which is designed to allow other developers to access their panel with ease, but there's a risk this could be exploited so i may switch to `bindingname`.

I've already written the code to create one of these panels based upon variables, as well as the code to typecast down to the label and image levels based on a nested iterative `.children` and `FindComponent` loop, and i can freely change the text of the labels or the image (with `.loadfromfile`) using this method (i.e. the code works). However, as i'm wanting to open this feature to other applications and developers to actually display information inside one of these "panels", i need to work with Shared Memory.

The problem is that i truly can't understand it. Everything i've read implies that using SharedMem is easy, but i just can't understand it at all. Even the simple example in XE2's included samples confuses me. I unfortunately don't understand IPC at all, despite trying numerous times to get a grasp on it. I could use inifiles, but i don't feel they have flexibility required. I considered `GlobalAtomTable`, but as with SharedMem, i don't understand that either, not to mention that it reportedly leaks in Delphi.

Essentially, i'm looking for a function/procedure where i first create the area of shared memory. I'm then really looking for a function to read a string from that sharedmemory and output the `result` for me to access via other procedures or functions. As i'd like to make my other projects compatible with this one, i'd also be looking to get a procedure/function to write values to the shared memory from a seperate application.

As i said, i don't understand IPC or SharedMem, and i really need a basic start point from which i can work and teach myself, up to the more advanced levels. A step-by-step Walkthrough on exactly what i'm hoping to learn would be much appreciated. I am wanting to learn this rather than just get a lump of code as it's pretty much a given that i should be working with IPC by now.

Comment: Shared memory is not the answer. You need to synchronize. It's far too low level for your needs. Something built on top of TCP/IP sounds more sensible and would be cross-platform easily. And could easily scale to remote machines.

Comment: @ken I think by SharedMem Scott means shared memory as in CreateFileMapping.

Comment: @David, you're right. Read too fast (saw "ShareMem" instead of "SharedMem"), and stopped reading too soon. :) Deleting the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [Cromis IMC or IPC components](http://www.cromis.net/blog/2012/04/cromis-library-updated/).

The [IMC](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-imc/) is for inter machine communication using tcp (indy) and the [IPC](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-ipc/) is for inter process communication using windows named pipes.

Both uses the same client/server message system(packet based), so you don't have to dwell over the windows documentation to implement your application.

Just follow the examples found on the links above and you would have your application running in no time. Btw, the author [`Iztok Kacin`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118765/runner) is a SO member.

Comment: This is probably the best example since i can work with the code and experiment (and it's pretty much exactly what i was looking for hence the accept). There was an initial issue when i downloaded the whole Cromis Library (required OverbyteICS and thus confused me due to Indy being mentioned), but that was soon solved with just the IPC package.

My one concern is whether or not this method is standard, and whether other developers outside of Delphi would be able to work with my application in the way i originally described if i use such an implementation.

Comment: I only am sending text strings back and forth between my client/servers. That way I can use the same transport for Com/DCom/Ipc/Tcp/Http layers. The text strings can be structured as xml data (or ini-file data), so the transport is very general and the protocol interface part can easily be described. Other solutions might be involve `DataSnap`,`XML-RPC` or `JSON`. I suggest you experiment a little, try to keep the protocol as independent of the transport as possible. When you are satisfied, look at the alternatives I mentioned and perhaps ask another question about pros and cons.

Comment: Hi, my IPC and IMC use high level abstraction to hide the implementation details from the developer as LU RD said. Because of custom protocol you need my components on server and client side to communicate. If you need something more open look for different solution. IMC uses TCP and Indy and IPC uses named pipes. But both have custom protocol behind so that they can send data packets in most optimal way.